# Cannot save Python Dataflow template to bucket when using a callable for WriteToBigQuery's table parameter

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow

Error in question:

`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'tableId'`

Code in question:

```
def get_table_spec(row: Dict[str, str]):
    data = json.loads(opts.data.get())
    network = data['network']
    gco = opts.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
    project = gco.project

    return f'{gco.project}:reports.{network}'

result = rows | 'SaveToBigQueryTable' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
    table=get_table_spec,
    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
```

So this works locally when I use the DirectRunner.
`python -m template --runner DirectRunner --otherargs ...`
No errors are thrown, data gets saved into my BigQuery table.

When I attempt to compile and deploy the template to a bucket `python -m template --runner DataflowRunner --template_location ... --staging_location etc...` It throws the error above.

Tried on version 2.15 and 2.16 of Apache Beam for Python.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to use dynamic destinations when writing to BigQuery was introduced in the 2.12.0 release of the Python SDK. This is due to a new [BigQuery sink](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.16.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#module-apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery) which is marked as experimental.

To use it with the `DataflowRunner` on recent SDKs you can add this flag to your `python` command:

```
--experiments use_beam_bq_sink
```

Comment: Yeah I saw this when I was browsing the code itself, but it doesn't seem to work due to an error with requiring a schema (which I thought wasn't required if you aren't creating the table). Will update this comment with the actual error later on when I tried to set the schema to autodetect (which also didn't work)

Comment: You should be using `beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery` instead of `beam.io.WriteToBigQuery`. I have a minimal example [here](https://github.com/gxercavins/dataflow-samples/blob/master/UTILS/dynamic-bq-writes/python/dynamic-bq-writes.py) where I don't pass any schema

Comment: Apologies! This task was shelved but I will be trying out what you said! I am definitely not using `beam.io.gcp.bigquery` so I'll fix that up. will report soon